# Remove the parent element from JSON reply

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I have a route used for AJAX calls. It gets items from a DB and returns a JSON array.

I'm using:

```
return reply({
   myArray
}).code(200);
```

Everything works but my output in the browser is:

```
{  
   "myArray":[  
    {  
       "_id":"1",
       "name":"Asd1"
      },
    {  
      "_id":"2",
      "name":"Asd2"
    }
}
```

But what I need is:

```
{  
  [  
    {  
       "_id":"1",
       "name":"Asd1"
      },
    {  
      "_id":"2",
      "name":"Asd2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Very basically, I need to get rid the "myArray" parent element and leave just the array there. It looks like a simple task but I can't find documentation or samples anywhere.

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: The json you need seems to be wrong.

Comment: You cant have an array straight like that to be valid JSON...https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You are right. Actually I need the array in the correct form you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
{  
  [  
    {  
       "_id":"1",
       "name":"Asd1"
    },
    {  
      "_id":"2",
      "name":"Asd2"
    }
  ]
}
```

is invalid JSON notation. Within curly braces, you should have key-value pairs where keys are strings and values are valid JSON values (strings, numbers, booleans, `null`, arrays, or objects).

Perhaps what you expect is just the array:

```
[  
  {  
     "_id":"1",
     "name":"Asd1"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"2",
    "name":"Asd2"
  }
]
```

which is valid JSON. In this case, you may simply send it to your `reply` function:

```
return reply(myArray).code(200);
```

For more info on JSON notation, see [the article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and play with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to develop better intuition on when the JSON you see is valid or not.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try that in first place. Thank you for your help, this works.